# Distribute objects in Concentric Circles

Tags: trigonometry, graph-theory, circles

I am attempting to distrubute objects evenly in concentric circles according to the following rules.

1. There will always be 1 object at the centre of the plane at $(0,0)$.
2. Each circle will have ***n*** elements which need to be distributed.
3. The number of each element in the circle is known as ***k***.
4. The circles level, known as ***h***, starts at 1 at the center object.
5. Every element has a parent, of which it has a direct relation. Each element should be at one level more than its parent.
6. No element shall have more than 1 parent, or be its own parent.
7. A parent may have 0 to many children.
8. With the exception of the first circle, each element should be distributed in respect to the elements parent to no more than half of its parent's angle.

   - This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyiRT.png) gives more context here but a way of explaining this is if each parent has a pie wedge, which is half way between it and ***k-1*** and ***k+1***, then each child element should sit between these two points.
9. The radius of the circles is known as ***r***.

The purpose of this is to generate a hierarchy of people and who they report to in an organisation.

I can currently generate the second circle's distribution via the formula:

- ***x = Parent_x + r cos(2kπ/n)***
- ***y = Parent_y + r sin(2kπ/n)***

However, I am unsure as to how to proceed for ***h >= 3***

Comment: By "circle level" do you mean the labelling number of the circle ?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to replace the tag "linear algebra" (no connection here with vector, matrices, linear spaces...) by "graph theory" : your graph here is in fact a tree.

Comment: Thus, you have a (abstract, i.e., computer science) "tree structure" and you want a (concrete, graphical) "harmonious blossoming" structure to render it. Could we say that a first approach would be to define circle sectors, centered at the origin in such a way that any "parent" at any level of the tree "has" his/her descendants in this sector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this hierarchical structure is a rooted tree. So will be using graph theory notation.

One possible way of approaching this is to allocate a sector for each node. That is, allocate sector $(0,2\pi)$ for the root. From here on, it should just be a matter of allocating the right sector to each vertex.

Let $v$ be a vertex that has been allocated a sector, call it $(a_v,b_v)$. Suppose $v$ has $k$ children $\{v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_{k-1}\}$. Assign sector 
$$\left(a_v+\frac{(b_v-a_v)i}{k},a_v+\frac{(b_v-a_v)(i+1)}{k}\right)$$
to $v_i$.

This should define a sector for each vertex of the tree. Now, to actually compute coordinates for each vertex, let $v$ be a vertex of the tree and let $d$ be the distance from the root to $v$. The coordinates for $v$ should be
$$dh\left(\cos\left(\frac{a_v+b_v}{2}\right),\sin\left(\frac{a_v+b_v}{2}\right)\right),$$
where $h$ is the increase in the radius of two consecutive circles.

Here is an example of the kind of layout this generates. Is this something like what you had in mind?

[image: example layout]

Could you possibly be looking for the "radial layout" of a tree? Was reminded of that term after trying to come up with a name for the image ;-)